# Populating tabs dynamically with AngularJS using Json data

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to angularjs,
I have this kind of json data

```
{
"City":[
{
    "name":"New York1",
    "alias":"NY1",
    "imgPath":"filePath/img1.jgp"
},
{
    "name":"New York2",
    "alias":"NY2",
    "imgPath":"filePath/img2.jgp"
},
{
    "name":"New York3",
    "alias":"NY3",
    "imgPath":"filePath/img3.jgp"
},
{
    "name":"New York4",
    "alias":"NY4",
    "imgPath":"filePath/img4.jgp"
}
]
}
```

;

I want to dynamically add tabs for 'name', when i click on a tab suppose there will be 
New York1,New York2,New York3,New York4  4 tabs its should display the rest of the data (i.e. alias,imgPath etc.).

I will be very thankful if any one can help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the core idea:

First, you have to get your JSON data for tabs via $http like:

```
//I put dummy path of your json file
    $http.get('../Resource/navs.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.listNavs= data;
    });
```

After that, you must only use ng-repeat to list your meta-data of tabs saved in *$scope.listNavs*:

```
//I forgot to put the CSS class from Bootstrap
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-repeat="navs in listNavs">      
            <li><a><img src="{{navs.imgPath}}"/>{{navs.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this is idea will be helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for your help          but i am completely new for angularjs can you please explain about the name tab i mean how to get 'name' dynamically. and one more thing i am not suppose to use html code for this functionality

Comment: In AngularJS tag is explained that its goal is to shim the browser to augment the HTML vocabulary with directives useful for building dynamic web applications. 
**That means that you can't use AngularJS without HTML**. 
You could also create your own service to get your 'config' for your tabs.
This is actually one of many dynamic solution that I gave you, I used $http to get your data from json and
ng-repeat, which allows you to iterate every item (_navs_) in list (_listNavs_), so you avoid to write your tabs like _<li><a><img src="filePath/img1.jgp"/>New York1</a></li>_ and so on.

Comment: Dear arman1991 my requirement is something like this http://liveweave.com/ZbLoKM with only difference is in place of Jquery  i need to use angularjs